# Web dash to .exe

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I have a program(.exe) c#, I need to access the platform remotely.( the logic is latency sensitive so I cannot make it into an api, webapp).

My issue is, I do not want to RDP to my remote server everytime to view the data, so my thought is to make a web based dashboard, and connect it to my exe / program to get the data.

I do not know if this is efficient, or possible. I am here to ask what is the most efficient / elegant way to achieve this.

I am thinking of building a middleware(API) that will allow the program to send request to the frontend to display the data, the data will be changing rapidly and I feel the sending that many request can cause latency in the program itself.

Any input on to achieve this?

Comment: Why you cannot make it into an api or webapp ? What is the latency, microseconds ?

Comment: Yes, its a trading application. The issue is I want to view my data without the need to RDP / SSH to the instance. Also having the program run the logic at set points, an api will not be able to do this.

Comment: not sure why you mention RDP/SSH, and by "set points" too, what exactly you are going to do ?

Comment: I am wanting to view my program data, without the need to RDP/SSH. Basically stating the use case for my web panel. The program takes a csv file and sets plot points in a visual graph, that is what I want to display on the web panel.

Comment: there are many ways to do it, look at the ASP.NET & HTML 5